# Are there boots made for a longer 2nd toe?

Tags: boots, footwear

I have a longer 2nd toe than the big toe ([Morton's toe or royal toe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morton%27s_toe)). The major problem is finding boots or sports shoes that fit properly. If I didn't have this longer toe I would wear a 9 or 9.5 (depending on the manufacturer) but with the toe I am forced to go a size larger or be in pain. When playing sports like hockey, rugby or rock climbing, I buy the smaller size and let the toe get bunched up. It will be less than an hour so I can suffer through it. In hiking and such where the activity will be a lot longer I can't last that long and need to buy the larger boot so I am not in pain. The problem then comes that my foot slides around in the boot which causes slipping problems when on rocky terrain and blisters from ill fitting shoes.

Are there any companies that design boots to accommodate the 2nd toe and still keep a nice snug fit on the foot?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not aware of any boots for your specific need, but there may be some other options using a larger size boot.

Preferably you should have little if any pressure from your toes against the front of your boot. For me, the solution to a loose boot has been to add a second insole which keeps a laced boot snug at the ankle while leaving the toes with room to move. I would have preferred a single thicker insole, but it wasn't thick enough for my needs.

There are also different lacing techniques that may help secure the boot at the ankle. [Backpacker](http://www.backpacker.com/gear/5245) has a bunch of descriptions and photos including:

> **Boot Heel Lock**
>
> To distribute pressure create a loop between two hooks
>   and pass the lace from above and through, then continue upward.
>
> [image]

Comment: I haven't thought about lacing around the heel. In the past, I have unlaced the bottom 2 holes in my climbing shoes to allow the toe knuckle to pop up through there and that helps. I will try this and see if there is a better fit around the rest of the foot.

Answer (score 1):

Technica
I just read about these, so haven't tried them out yet, but they look amazing.  They're molded around your individual feet, and are thus supposed to be a perfect fit.  They have a boot, and a hiking shoe. I'll be purchasing soon. 
https://www.tecnicasports.com/cas-concept/

Comment: looks promising. I wonder if they have a "Love it" guarantee. they dont looks cheap and if they dont work right after all that work, it would suck